# Run an FTP commands batch file from C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I have written a winform app in C# which modifies FTP commands in a script file (server address etc..) and then executes a batch file that is supposed to start FTP from command prompt and download files according to script.

When i run the Batch file external to app (from command prompt or double click), the files are being downloaded fine, but when executing the batch from the app nothing happens...

I also noticed following difference:
When running batch externally I see "**ftp>** open 10.1.1.1" in cmd window.
When running batch from the app I see "open 10.1.1.1" in cmd window,(missing the "ftp>").

My guess is that I'm not using System.Diagnostics.Process() correctly...

C# relevant part:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            var cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "runFTP.bat";
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
            cmd.Start();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            cmd.Close();
        }

    }
```

Batch file (runFTP.bat):

```
echo off

@echo Downloading files...
REM ==Start FTP with script==

ftp -i -s:ftpCmd.txt

del ftpCmd.txt

@echo Done!
@echo Exiting...
```

FTP script file (ftpCmd.txt):

```
open 10.1.1.1
user
password
bin
cd /rootFolder/new
lcd C:\Downloads
mget *.*
bye
```

Comment: Can you redirect `ftp` output to a file in both scenarios and share the output here?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem.. works fine now :)

By adding and changing in C# the following System.Diagnostics.Process() StartInfo parameters to false, I was able to download the files
and get the missing "ftp>" on command prompt.

Modified C# code looks like this

```
            var cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "runFTP.bat";
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
            cmd.Start();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            cmd.Close();
```

Thanks to anyone spent time on this.. hope this will contribute to someone else.

Comment: can we use the same for uploading files to the server using put?